# using win32com.client in python how to find and replace multiple text

Tags: ms-word, python

I'm trying to add multiple string values to a Word document using find and replace with the [win32com.client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) Python library.

I can find and replace one value, but I don't know how to do this for multiple values.

This is what I have so far:

```
import win32com.client
word = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
word.DisplayAlerts = 0
word.Documents.Open("C:\TEMP\Testing\Me.docx")
word.Selection.Find
find.Text = "First Name"
find.Replacement.Text = "John"
find.Execute(Replace=1, Forward=True)

# the following part doesn't run
find.Text = "Last Name"             
find.Replacement.Text = "Smith"
find.Execute(Replace=1, Forward=True)

word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs('C:\TEMP\Testing\Me2.docx')
word.Quit() # releases Word object from memory
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import win32com.client
from os import getcwd, listdir

docs = [i for i in listdir('.') if i[-3:]=='doc' or i[-4:]=='docx'] #All Word file

FromTo = {"First Name":"John",
          "Last Name":"Smith"} #You can insert as many as you want


word = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True #Keep comment after tests
word.DisplayAlerts = False

for doc in docs:
    word.Documents.Open('{}\\{}'.format(getcwd(), doc))
    for From in FromTo.keys():
        word.Selection.Find.Text = From
        word.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = FromTo[From]
        word.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace=2, Forward=True) #You made the mistake here=> Replace must be 2  
    name = doc.rsplit('.',1)[0]
    ext = doc.rsplit('.',1)[1]
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs('{}\\{}_2.{}'.format(getcwd(), name, ext))

word.Quit() # releases Word object from memory
```