# Finding word on page(s) in document

Tags: python, python-docx, pdfminer

I am looking for an elegant solution to find on what page(s) in a document a certain word occurs that I have stored in a python dictionary/list.

I first considered .docx format as an input and had a look at [PythonDocx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) which has a search function, but there's obviously not really a pages attribute in the docx/xml format.
If I parse the document I could look for `<w:br w:type="page"/>` occurrences in the xml tree but unfortunately these do not show non-forced page breaks.

I even considered converting files to PDF first and use something like [PDFminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) to parse the document page-wise.

Is there any straightforward solution to search a .docx document for a string and return the pages it occurs on like

```
[('foo' ,[1, 4, 7 ]), ('bar', [2]), ('baz', [2, 5, 8, 9 )]
```

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571905/finding-on-which-page-a-search-string-is-located-in-a-pdf-document-using-python)

Comment: @birgit Are you still looking for a solution on this topic?

Comment: @mabe02 I haven't found a working solution yet no:/ but would be interested

Answer (score 3):

## Parse the xml files composing the docx

It seems that the biggest challenge in your question is how to be able to parse a document page by page. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696803) of a word document is not always the same and it depends on the margins, the paper sheet settings, the application you use to open it etc. A good reasoning on the accuracy of any script for this purpose can be found at [google group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595864/python-create-a-table-of-contents-with-python-docx-lxml).

However, if you can be satisfied with a almost 100% accurate, you start to find a solution as suggested in this [google group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595864/python-create-a-table-of-contents-with-python-docx-lxml):

> I found that I can unzip the .docx file and extract `docProps/app.xml`, then parse the XML with ElementTree to get the `<Pages></Pages>` element. I found that most of the time that number is accurate, but I've seen a few instances where the number in that element is not correct.

## Use Win32com.Client

Another approach could be to use `win32com.client` to open the file, paginate it, make your search and then return the results in the format you want it.

You can find an example of the syntax in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696803):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
#open Word
word = Dispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False
word = word.Documents.Open(doc_path)

#get number of sheets
word.Repaginate()
num_of_sheets = word.ComputeStatistics(2)
```

You can also have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18216969) regarding **find and replace** in a word document using win32com.client.

Comment: @birgit so does it answer to your question? was it useful?